# Создание PDF файла в Oracle и отправка по почте

Tags: oracle

Мне нужна функция, которая будет брать данные из таблицы и формировать pdf файл. В котором должен быть титульный лист, логотип и прочее визуальное оформление. После чего он должен быть отправлен по почте. Мне не нужен код, просто идеи как это сделать и объяснение, почему именно так. Пока у меня нет никаких идей

Comment: идея проста: ищете pdf-библиотеку (написанную на pl/sql или java) и вызываете её.

Comment: @ESkri, так вот вопрос что за библиотека, гугл выдал oracle publisher, но он скорее платный чем нет

Comment: не поверю, что для джавы нет библиотеки работы с pdf.  для джавы есть всё. )))

Comment: @ESkri, джаву я не знаю, решил делать это на js посмотрим, что получится, но это костыль прям

Comment: джава встроена в оракловую базу.  а JS - нет.

Comment: @ESkri, в APEX встроенна, даже с jquery, так что вариант вполне рабочий